# How do I read the rows of a specific column in c?

Tags: c, file, csv, stream, fgets

I've tried multiple stuff as reading new lines after checking if that columns is "General" but still does not work at all. It is an `csv` file and it would be lines with commas after each `fgets` and i need a specific column with it's data.

Here's my code:

```
char fi[1024];
while(!feof(CsvFile)){
    //Read
    fgets(fi, 1024, CsvFile);
    if(strstr(fi, "General") == 0){
        fscanf(CsvFile, "%[^\n]s", fi);
        printf("%s", fi);
    }
    fgetc(CsvFile);
}
```

It does not print what i want.

Comment: "does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact file input, the expected output and actual output.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Can you provide the `csv` file´s content and what you want from it in detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a CSV file is **much more complicated than you assumed** (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). You must take all kind of rules into account. For instance, if a cell contains a comma, the content must be surrounded by `"`.

However, you can implement a **simplified version** which assumes:

- a CSV file is made of lines;
- a line is MAX_LINE characters, at most;
- a line is made of cells;
- a cell ends with comma or new-line;
- a cell contains anything but comma or new-line.

The code below reads one line at a time and then uses [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to split the line into cells.

*Welcome to SO and good luck!*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1024

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  //
  FILE* fp = fopen( "c:\\temp\\so.txt", "r" );
  if ( !fp )
  {
    printf( "could not open file" );
    return -1;
  }

  //
  char line[ MAX_LINE + 1 ];
  while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ) / sizeof( *line ), fp ) ) // get a line
  {
    int col_idx = 0;
    const char* sep = "\r\n,"; // cells are separated by a comma or a new line
    char* cell = strtok( line, sep ); // find first cell
    while ( cell )
    {
      // your processing code goes here
      cell = strtok( NULL, sep ); // next cell
      col_idx++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```